# Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm learning SQL.
I'm trying to insert data. My MySQL database looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE category (
  category_id CHAR(100),
  category_name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
)
```

I ran this command

```
INSERT INTO category (category_name) VALUES ("test");
```

But I got this error

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to have an autoincrementing category ID?  Or will you have one you're passing in?

Comment: Yes i want to have autoincrementing category ID. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Just answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an incrementing ID it would need to be an int.   You Generally want to make ID's integers not chars to speed up lookup regardless.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (
   `category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `category_name` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

That will let you insert without adding your own ID, and automatically generate unique ID's for the records.

Issue was you set your category_id field to not have a default value and also not allow null, which means you -have- to set a value for it in the insert.  If you wanted to use your existing table you would need to do this:

```
INSERT INTO category (category_id, category_name) VALUES ("someid", "test");
```